# SDFatLib for Python?

Tags: python, sd-card, microcontroller, fat

**Scenario:**

I've got a TTL-JPEG Camera, SD Card Holder Board, and a Synapse RF Module to play with.  Trying to combine these 3 devices to create a wireless camera that can shoot videos, store them on the SD card using SPI, and then retrieve them as needed over a wireless link to a Windows PC.  I am confident that I wired everything correctly.

**Problem:**

The problem lies in the software.  Synapse RF Modules use SNAPpy, which is a subset of Python.  And I believe SDFatLib is written in C/C++.  So there is a conflict in language.  This is a problem because SDFatLib holds all of the secrets to managing files on SD Cards.

**Question:**

I see a few different pathways to travel.  One is trying to recreate SDFatLib in Python; another is to change microcontrollers.  A third option is to maybe create my own simple file system on the SD card that can only store video (series of images) and pictures (single image) rather than using FAT32.  If none of these approaches work, what would anyone suggest?

Comment: Does SNAPpy support calling C/C++ code? Regular python has several ways to do this as suggested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python